# C# Entity Framework CS1941

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to use linq with Entity Framework. In below code first join is red squiggle and I have this error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1941  The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is
>   incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'

Code

```
var vals = (from o in db.Words 
            join r in db.Results 
            on o.Id equals r.root   
            join s in db.Senses on r.Id equals s.results_id

            select  o ).Take(10) ;
```

**EDIT:**

After comments and realized my mistaken code I have decided add my entity class. 
When I run my project then entity framework creates  Id and root_Id columns on Sql Server then I considered I can use ***Resultset.root equals Words.Id***  structure

```
public class Word{
   [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
   ...}

 public class Result{
   [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Word root { get; set; }
   ...}

public class Result{
   [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Result result { get; set; }
   ...}
```

And Context class

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext{
 ...
 public DbSet<Word>        Words               { get; set; }
 public DbSet<Result>      Results             { get; set; }
 public DbSet<Sens>        Senses              { get; set; }
 ...
}
```

Id and root isnot compatible types but when I change the query with compatible ones problem is continuing. What do I go wrong. Thanks. Greetings

Comment: We have no idea what the types returned by `Words`, `Results` etc look like.

Answer (score 5):

`r.Id` and `s.Id` have different types. Check them.
Maybe they are `int` and `long` or something else.

From @OzanTopal:

For more information check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1941

Comment: exactly. for more information check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1941)  @Tekin Güllü

Answer (score 1):

You are joining 3 tables but the result is just:

`select  o`?

What is the purpose of your join?

Check the answer above or check also this if it is different types:

```
on o.Id equals r.root
on r.Id equals s.Id 
r.val== SomeVal
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is because the Id properties of Sense and Result types are incompatible. They don't have to be same. For example, its Okay (from compiler's perspective) for one to be int and another to be long. However, for example, string and int or Guid or int would be incompatible. The solution is to make both types compatible if not same. I understand that you may not be able to do so since your entity model may be built from the existing database and you may not have authority or may not want to change the underlying type of the columns.

If you want to solve the compilation problem in the code itself then you will have to do explicit type casting:

```
var vals = (from o in db.Words 
            join r in db.Results 
            on o.Id equals r.root   
            join s in db.Senses on r.Id equals Convert.ToString(s.Id)
            where r.val== SomeVal
            select  o ).Take(10);
```

This assumes that the Id property of the Result class is string while the Id of the Sense class is some numeric type.